# Python: Write list to individual columns in each row

Tags: python, csv

I'm writing data to a CSV but the current output is as follows:
(the top row is the headers)

```
 A    VC_s                                       VC_i    VT_s
 1    (['Not Reported'],['reported'],['click'])   
 2    (['Not Reported'],['reported'],['click'])
```

The **desired** output is as follows:

```
 A    VC_s            VC_i         VT_s
 1    Not Reported    reported     click
 2    Not Reported    reported     click
```

The code I've got so far is:

```
ifile = csv.reader(open("input.csv",'rb'))
shutil.copy("input.csv","temp")
tempfile = csv.reader(open("temp","rb"))
ofile = csv.writer(open("RESULTS.csv","ab"))

for row in ifile:
    #do some table scraping stuff here
    VC_s = str(cells[1].find(text=True))
    VC_i = str(cells[2].find(text=True))
    VT_s = str(cells[4].find(text=True))

    entry = ([VC_s], [VC_i], [VT_s])
    rowAdd = tempfile.next()
    ofile.writerow(rowAdd + [entry])
```

What am i doing wrong and how can I fix this? It would seem like an easy fix but I am stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
entry = [VC_s, VC_i, VT_s]
rowAdd = tempfile.next()
ofile.writerow(rowAdd + entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want `entry = [VC_s, VC_i, VT_s]`